# I need to Update the x-axis value 1-8 in a chart library android

Tags: android, achartengine, linegraph

> I have placed a chart library graph in my app, but the x-axis values are rounded off like 0,2,6,8 i want to show it as 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8.
>
> LineChart.java

```
import org.achartengine.ChartFactory;
import org.achartengine.GraphicalView;
import org.achartengine.chart.PointStyle;
import org.achartengine.model.XYMultipleSeriesDataset;
import org.achartengine.model.XYSeries;
import org.achartengine.renderer.XYMultipleSeriesRenderer;
import org.achartengine.renderer.XYSeriesRenderer;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;

public class LineChart extends Activity {
    public static final String TYPE = "type";
    private XYMultipleSeriesDataset mDataset = getDemoDataset();
    private XYMultipleSeriesRenderer mRenderer = getDemoRenderer();
    private GraphicalView mChartView;

    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_line_chart);

        setRendererStyling();
        if (mChartView == null) {
            LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.chart);
            mChartView = ChartFactory.getLineChartView(this, mDataset,
                    mRenderer);
            mRenderer.setSelectableBuffer(100);
            layout.addView(mChartView, new LayoutParams(
                    LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));
        } else
            mChartView.repaint();
    }

    private void setRendererStyling() {
        mRenderer.setApplyBackgroundColor(true);
        mRenderer.setBackgroundColor(Color.argb(100, 50, 50, 50));
        mRenderer.setAxisTitleTextSize(16);
        mRenderer.setChartTitleTextSize(20);
        mRenderer.setLabelsTextSize(15);
        mRenderer.setLegendTextSize(15);
        mRenderer.setMargins(new int[] { 20, 30, 15, 0 });
        mRenderer.setZoomButtonsVisible(true);
        mRenderer.setPointSize(10);
    }

    private XYMultipleSeriesDataset getDemoDataset() {
        double[] seriesFirstY = {20,-20,67,180,-45,24,99,-34,-8};
        double[] seriesSecondY = {10,80,-40,-20,135,24,199,-34,80};

        XYMultipleSeriesDataset dataset = new XYMultipleSeriesDataset();

        XYSeries firstSeries = new XYSeries("Sample series One");
        for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++)
            firstSeries.add(i, seriesFirstY[i]);
        dataset.addSeries(firstSeries);

        XYSeries secondSeries = new XYSeries("Sample series Two");
        for (int j = 0; j < 9; j++)
            secondSeries.add(j, seriesSecondY[j]);
        dataset.addSeries(secondSeries);
        return dataset;
    }

    private XYMultipleSeriesRenderer getDemoRenderer() {
        XYMultipleSeriesRenderer renderer = new XYMultipleSeriesRenderer();
        renderer.setMargins(new int[] { 20, 30, 15, 0 });
        XYSeriesRenderer r = new XYSeriesRenderer();
        r.setColor(Color.BLUE);
        r.setPointStyle(PointStyle.SQUARE);
        r.setFillBelowLine(true);
        r.setFillBelowLineColor(Color.WHITE);
        r.setFillPoints(true);
        renderer.addSeriesRenderer(r);
        r = new XYSeriesRenderer();
        r.setPointStyle(PointStyle.CIRCLE);
        r.setColor(Color.GREEN);
        r.setFillPoints(true);
        renderer.addSeriesRenderer(r);
        renderer.setAxesColor(Color.DKGRAY);
        renderer.setLabelsColor(Color.LTGRAY);
        return renderer;
    }
}
```

> activity_Line_chart.xml
>
> Layout for displaying the graph

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/chart"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.81"
        android:orientation="horizontal" />
</LinearLayout>
```

[Referred from this site](http://www.oodlestechnologies.com/blogs/Drawing-graphs-in-Android-using-aChartEngine-charting-library-(Line-Charts))

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You have an option to set a number of labels for desired axis. In your case you need this piece of code

```
mRendererHR.setXLabels(8);
```